# How to change FOSUserBundle template dynamically in controller?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to change confirmation template in my controller dynamically. How can I do it easily?

Here is my config:

```
fos_user:
    [...]
    registration:
        form:
            type: madden_user_registration
            handler: madden_user.registration.form.handler
        confirmation:
            enabled:    true
            template: MaddenUserBundle:Registration:email_confirm.{locale}.html.twig
            from_email:
                address:        %mailer_from%
                sender_name:    %mailer_registration_name%
```

In my controller I have:

```php
$confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');
$formHandler = $this->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
$formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: can you show me the code of "return" of your action controller ?